# how to get a `.ipa` file from create-react-native-app?

Tags: react-native

I use [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app), and I wonder how I can get a `.ipa` file to run in my iPhone from it? I see the command `npm run eject`, but I do not know what to do next. And for some reason, I cannot use `exp` in the command line.

Is there a detail instructions to solve my problem? thanks

Comment: You could open the project from XCODE and get it from there instead of from command line

Answer (score 3):

`npm run eject` will not create a IPA file for you. It will just create project files for iOS and Android which you can run on their respective IDE's. i.e Xcode and Android Studio.

Here is a good document which you can use to build iOS without ejecting it : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html

If you choose to eject then, open Xcode project from the iOS folder -> change the bundle id. and follow along this https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?34616,HowTo%3A+Create+an+.ipa+file+from+XCode,

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to use expo too, but when I run `exp login` in the command line, I cannot login, it says " There was a problem understanding the server. Please try again." , and I don't know why

Comment: follow the instructions, I stop here, why my export button is unclickable? https://ws3.sinaimg.cn/large/006tNc79gy1fpkttalye3j30d80a40ty.jpg

Comment: You also must have a paid developer account for generating IPA file. For individual account, its $99.

Answer (score 0):

I xcode:

1. Change scheme destination to `generic ios device`
2. Go to `Product` - `Archive`
3. Go to `Window` - `Organizer`
4. Select the archive you want, click `export`

There you should be able to choose method and destination.

Comment: the `export` button is gray, so i must pay for it for $99? any other solutions? I just want to see the result personally in my iPhone

Comment: You have to set up personal developer account which is free and I am not sure about this, but it should let you create ipa which should work atleast 24h before need to re-export it.